# induction proof for T(n) = T(n/2) + clog(n) = O(log(n)^2)

Tags: algorithm, proof

`log() = log base 2 of ()`
`log()^2 = log^2 base 2 of ()`

I'm stuck with this induction proof. I have the following recurrence relation

`T(n) = T(n/2) + Theta(log(n))`

I have to prove that `T(n) = O(log(n)^2)`

making the constants explicit:

`T(n) = T(n/2) + clog(n)`

I know that for O's definition I must find `k > 0` and `n' > 0` so that `t(n) <= k(log(n)^2)` for every `n >= n'`

`T(n) = O(log(n)^2)` supposed true for every `m < n` I have that `t(m) <= k(log(m)^2)` is true :

given
`T(n) <= k(n/2)(log(n/2)^2) + c log(n) =`
`= k(n/2)(log(n)^2 - 1) + c log(n)` 
`= k(n/2)(log(n)^2)) - kn/2 + c log(n)` .

So

`k(n/2)(log(n)^2) - kn/2 + c log(n) <=? k(log(n)^2)` <--- that's where I'm stuck

I can't find any `k` nor `n` that will make this works, where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show for some fixed α, M > 0 of our choice that T(n) ≤ α (log(n) + 1) log(n) + M, since this function is O(log(n)²). You didn't give us a base case, so let's just assume that this holds for sufficiently small n (without loss of generality by setting M as needed).

The inductive step is showing that T(n/2) ≤ α (log(n/2) + 1) log(n/2) + M implies T(n) ≤ α (log(n) + 1) log(n) + M. We have

```
T(n)
= T(n/2) + c log(n)
≤ α (log(n/2) + 1) log(n/2) + M + c log(n)
= α log(n) (log(n) − 1) + M + c log(n).
```

If we set α = c/2, then

```
T(n)
≤ α log(n) (log(n) − 1) + M + 2 α log(n).
= α (log(n) + 1) log(n) + M.
```